# ORA-01847 Error to get a date

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having a problem with this query:

```
select to_char(ADD_MONTHS((LAST_DAY(to_date(DATEVAR, 'yyyymmdd'))+1),-1),'yyyymmdd') from mytable 
where ROWNUM=1 
and var = to_char(last_day(to_date(DATEVAR, 'yyyyMMdd')), 'WW')-1;
```

I want it to return when the var is the last week number of the month and return null when it isn't if my var is '29' (weekNumber) i get:

> ORA-01847: "day of month must be between 1 and last day of month"

But if i change the week number to '30'(last week number of the month) i get the correct result:

```
'20160701'
```

Please help thank you.

Comment: Last week number? last week number of the month is 30? How do you expect to write correct code, when your mind is confused between "week" and "day"? There is no way to write correct code from confused thinking. Regardless of anything else, your very last line will fail: you compute a `to_char()` of something (doesn't matter what) and then you subtract 1 from the resulting character string. You need a different approach to asking your question: State what you are trying to do, what your data looks like and what output you want - don't just show your code (which doesn't work correctly anyway).

Comment: @mathguy but there are over 30 weeks in the year, so why would you assume that the OP is getting confused between days and week numbers?

Comment: ***Never***, *ever* call `to_date()` on `date` value.

Comment: @Boneist - or perhaps I am getting confused? What is the last week number of the month - weeks are numbered for the year, and we are looking at the highest week number for a week that overlaps with a given month? And we are supposed to be able to guess that, not from an explanation of the problem, but from reading someone's code for it?

Comment: @mathguy that's the meaning I understood from the OP's post - mainly from their description of their problem, not their code.

Comment: @Boneist - Ok, then I am the one who was confused. It has happened before.

Comment: @mathguy, eh, it's Friday! Also, I may have been known to get confused myself, on the odd occasion or two..... or lots! *{;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see an issue with your code? With var set to 30:

```
WITH mytable AS (SELECT trunc(SYSDATE, 'yyyy') - 1 + LEVEL datevar
                 FROM   dual
                 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 366)
SELECT to_char(add_months((last_day(datevar) + 1), -1), 'yyyymmdd') ret_col
FROM   mytable
WHERE  rownum = 1
AND    30 = to_number(to_char(last_day(datevar), 'WW'))- 1;

RET_COL
--------
20160701
```

Change the 30 to a 29 in the above query, and I get no rows returned.

The only thing that I can think is that your datevar column has a datatype of VARCHAR2 instead of DATE and that you're experiencing some implicit date conversion issues due to your NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting.

N.B. edited my query to remove the to_date()'s that were there on the datevar (which, as I'd defined the datevars as DATEs, was a very silly thing to do! Thanks @mathguy.) Also, added in an explicit to_number() in the where clause.

Comment: You are still relying on the same implicit conversion I pointed out in my comment to the OP - in the last row you are subtracting 1 from a string. This may be one of those cases when Oracle guesses correctly, but subtracting 1 from a string is generally not a good practice.

Comment: @mathguy in this instance, the implicit conversion of the string to a number is fairly safe. But I take your point and have added an explicit to_number()